# speed control of induction motor using MATLAB/Simulation and LABVIEW

Tags: matlab, labview

i need to know that can a MATLAB/Simulation model of variable frequency drive of induction motor be embedded into labview to control the physical induction motor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MATLAB script node in LabVIEW.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider [LabVIEW Control Design and Simulation Module](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/11281/en/).